# Python showing No module named 'pynput' even though installed

Tags: drivers, python

I have installed pynput module. But when I do `import pynput` , it shows the error given in the title.

[Here is the screenshot, showing successful installation of pynput module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDL64.png)

Comment: You haven't provided OS/release details, and please don't provide pictures of text, copy & paste the text itself (it's easier to read, plus we can copy/paste from it to provide you with clues or answers).

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1208706/edit) your question to provide the error message that you encountered. And make sure you are using the same Python version that you used to install `pynput` (i.e: Make sure that for example you installed it using Python 3 and you are using Python 3 too).

Comment: Probably you should run `pip3 install pynput`?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Its working. Thank you!

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Would you be willing to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in your screen output, `pip install` will install packages for Python version 2.x. However, you are probably using Python version 3.x. The `pip` *man* page specifies:

> On Debian, **pip** is the command to use when installing packages for
>   Python 2, while **pip3** is the command to use when installing packages for
>   Python 3.

So, you should use:

```
pip3 install pynput
```

to install packages for Python version 3.x.

I hope Python 2.x will be removed completely from Ubuntu versions released in 2020 and forward. And such misunderstandings will be eliminated too!